# Accordition Menu expand on specific URL

Tags: accordion

The accordition menu has some top level items, these items when clicked just expand the corresponding section of the menu. Is there a way these expansion to be triggered when URL contains some keyword? For example: When URL contains the keyword "dog" the top level "animals" auto-expand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fixed my issue using the following:

```
$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if ((false !== strpos($url,'dog')) &&  ($li->hasClass('animals'))){

$li->attr('class', sprintf('level1 animals active'));}
```

Like I needed when the keyword dog exists in url the "animals" menu is set active.